# Improvement of the config file management

Tags: python, configuration, project-structure, configuration-management

I am working on a personal project for more than 6 months now, this project is composed of three distinct parts, simulation (wrapping a software),
database related stuff (store the simulated data in a database) and modelization (a lot of machine learning related stuff)

To manage my config (paths and few constants) I started by putting all the variables into the config.py file at the root of the package (see below).

It worked surprisingly well. However there is a caveat, I generally work with simulation and database in tandem, or with database and modelization in tandem, the thing is, in this setup, I have all the path
of the project depending on one `experiment_name` present in the `config.py` file.

This situation worked surprisingly well when I was working only on database and simulation, but now the project is growing and it is not that good anymore.

Now I would need to be able to change the `experiment_name` when launching a test, however I like the fact that I can `import` all the path and constant by just doing
`import config as c`, (I can then do `c.path..` and know where does the variable come from).

I am searching a new way to handle the paths and config variable in my project. I am thinking about putting all the config file into a class and do something like `c = Config(experiment_name)`, I have two questions related to that:

- Is it a good idea/good practice ? Is there a better option ?
- Where should I create the object inside the core files ?

config.py

```
import socket
from pathlib import Path, PurePath

experiment_name = 'experiment_0'

enable_simulation = True
development_hostname = 'DESKTOP-VXXXX'


path_project = Path(__file__).parent.parent

path_experiments_folder = path_project.joinpath('experiments')
path_experiment_folder = path_experiments_folder.joinpath(experiment_name)
path_experiment_input_config = path_experiment_folder.joinpath('input.json')
path_experiment_output_config = path_experiment_folder.joinpath('output.json')

path_databases_folder = path_project.joinpath('databases')
path_experiment_database_folder = path_databases_folder.joinpath(experiment_name)

if socket.gethostname() != development_hostname and enable_simulation:
    run_simulation = True
    path_simulation_root_directory = PurePath('/home', 'thomas', 'FOLDER')
else:
    run_simulation = False
    path_simulation_root_directory = path_project.joinpath('FOLDER')

state = f"hostname {socket.gethostname()}, simulation {['OFF', 'ON'][run_simulation]}"
```

simulation/core.py

```
from .. import config as c
from utilities import sub_function


def function_that_i_call_in_my_scripts(path_experiment_input_config=None):
    path = path_experiment_input_config or c.path_experiment_input_config
    sub_function(path)


class ClassThatICallInMyScripts:
    def __init__(self, path_experiment_input_config=None):
        self.path_experiment_input_config = path_experiment_input_config or c.path_experiment_input_config

    def foo(self):
        return  # do something
```

simulation/utilities.py

```
def sub_function(path):
    print(f'do something in {path}')
```

idea of new config.py

```
import socket
from pathlib import Path, PurePath


class Config:
    def __init__(self, experiment_name, enable_simulation=True, development_hostname='DESKTOP-VXXXX'):
        self.experiment_name = experiment_name
        self.enable_simulation = enable_simulation
        self.development_hostname = development_hostname

        self.path_project = Path(__file__).parent.parent

        self.path_experiments_folder = self.path_project.joinpath('experiments')
        self.path_experiment_folder = self.path_experiments_folder.joinpath(experiment_name)
        self.path_experiment_input_config = self.path_experiment_folder.joinpath('input.json')
        self.path_experiment_output_config = self.path_experiment_folder.joinpath('output.json')

        self.path_databases_folder = self.path_project.joinpath('databases')
        self.path_experiment_database_folder = self.path_databases_folder.joinpath(experiment_name)

        if socket.gethostname() != development_hostname and enable_simulation:
            self.run_simulation = True
            self.path_simulation_root_directory = PurePath('/home', 'thomas', 'FOLDER')
        else:
            self.run_simulation = False
            self.path_simulation_root_directory = self.path_project.joinpath('FOLDER')

        self.state = f"hostname {socket.gethostname()}, simulation {['OFF', 'ON'][self.run_simulation]}"
```

Structure of the project, many paths depends of the `experiment_name`

```
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── simulation
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   └── utilities.py
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── initialization.py
│   │   ├── insert.py
│   │   └── retrieve.py
│   └── modelization
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── preprocessing.py
│       └── training.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_simulation
│   │   ├── test_run_simulation.py
│   │   └── test_multiprocessing.py
│   └── test_database
│       ├── test_initialization.py
│       ├── test_insert.py
│       └── test_retrieve.py
├── databases
│   └── experiment_0
│       ├── train.db
│       └── test.db
├── FOLDER
└── experiments
    └── experiment_0
        ├── output.json
        ├── input.json
        └──  source
            └── lot_of_files_for_simulation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would use a function that returns a dictionary instead of a class in config.py, e.g. like this:

```
import pathlib

def configure(experiment_name):
    config = {}
    config["simulation_base"] = pathlib.Path("~/simulation")
    config["experiment_base"] = pathlib.Path("~/experiments", experiment_name)
    return config
```

Then, when you use it like this:

```
from config import configure

my_config = configure("important experiment")
```

Why would I do it like this?

- The idea of a class is to encapsulate data and functions that use/manipulate that data. This does not seem to apply to your problem.
- A function maps better to the concept some data (experiment_name) in -> some data (config) out.
- A dict seems to provide all the functionality you need from your config.
- No need to type self all the time ;)

If you want to keep the .key access, you could simply convert the dict to a named_tuple before returning it:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyConfigTuple = namedtuple("MyCnfig", my_config)
my_config_as_named_tuple = MyConfigTuple(**my_config)
print(my_config_as_named_tuple.simulation_base)
```

In any case, the most important thing to consider in your case is probably: What will the me in 2 years want to change? And, is it worth to change the class I have already written to use another approach?

Comment: That seems such a good idea !
I implemented the day before the "idea of config", and it work quite well, but I think I'll certainly switch the class to the combination of function/dict :) Moreover the namedtuple approach is quite nice ! 
Thank you very much :)